# highchart mysql json with dropdown select value for where condition

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, highcharts

i'm trying to use highcharts using json data from mysql table. i want to set a drop down list with values that are going to be used as WHERE conditions for the mysql_query to fetch selected data and populate them in highchart.
the codes are working properly with static conditions (no drowpdown variables).

main.html

```
<form method="get" action="" >
Chose :
<select name="liste" id="liste">
<option value="A" <? if($selected == 'A'){ echo 'selected="Choice A"';}?>Choice A</option>
<option value="B" <? if($selected == 'B'){ echo 'selected="Choice B"';}?>Choice B</option>
<option value="C" <? if($selected == 'C'){ echo 'selected="Choice C"';} ?>Choice C</option>
<option value="D" <? if($selected == 'D'){ echo 'selected="Choice D"';} ?>Choice D</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

data.php

```
`<?php

$A=$_GET['liste'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","myuser","mypwd");

if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);

$test = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE table2.age LIKE '{$A}'");

$rowss = array();
while($rr = mysql_fetch_array($test)) { 
$ro[0] = $rr[0];
$ro[1] = $rr[1];
array_push($rowss,$ro); 
}

 print json_encode($rowss, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

 mysql_close($con);
?>
```

on the main.html file i have the highchart script that call the data.php file to get the json data.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
  //rest of the code
 $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
            options.series[0].data = json;
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
</script>
```

testing the data.php give the correct output according to the selected value. so i'm assuming that it is working fine. my problem is when loading the main.html it draws an empty graph and even when changing the value keep drawing empty data graph.

NB: i know `mysql_*` is no longer best practice and planing to switch to `mysqli_*` later.

EDIT:
seems like my `options.series[0]` options obj is not created and the console shows empty data array. when using `<form method="get" action="data.php" >` i got the expect array but cannot get the graph.

Comment: `options.series[0]` has your options obj been created yet ? Also have you tried $.ajax instead of getJSON ? And are there any error messages you are getting it the console ?

Comment: `$.ajax(
   url: data.php,
   data: queryOptions,
   dataType: 'json',
   success:function(json) {
                options.series[0].data = json;
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });` is it correct ?? don't know how to use ajax!!

Comment: I recommend you to remove php code from your select, then catch events by jquery (change function). In this action call ajax and then update your chart by series.update / series.setData

Comment: i removed the php code from the select. i think that the variable are not sent to data.php when action="".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got works as i wanted according to the following [example](http://www.theonlytutorials.com/highcharts-load-json-data-via-ajax-php/) i had to make ajax call to set the variable onchange of the drop menu and the code become like this (remove the form tag and submit button)
main.html:

```
<select name="list" id="list">
<option value="A">Choice A</option>
<option value="B">Choice B</option>
<option value="C">Choice C</option>
<option value="D">Choice D</option>
</select>

<script>
 $(function () {

  //on page load  
 getAjaxData("A");

 //on changing select option
 $('#list').change(function(){
 var val = $('#list').val();
 getAjaxData(val);
 });

 function getAjaxData(id){
 //use getJSON to get the dynamic data via AJAX call
 $.getJSON('data.php', {id: id}, function(chartData) {
 .....rest of the code
```

and the data.php:

```
 <?php

 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","myuser","mypwd");

 if (!$con) {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);

 $id = $_GET['id'];

 $test = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE table2.age LIKE '{$id}'");

 $rowss = array();
  while($rr = mysql_fetch_array($test)) { 
  $ro[0] = $rr[0];
  $ro[1] = $rr[1];
 array_push($rowss,$ro); 
 }

 print json_encode($rowss, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

  mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

enjoy it!!

Answer (score 0):

i try this query it give perfect graph.

```
      for (var i=0; i<data.value.length; i++)
     {
     **series**.push({
                    name: data.value[i].name,
                    data:data.value[i].value
                });
      }


        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'graph_view',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                    marginRight: 0,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                credits: {
            text: '',
            href: ''
            },
                title: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: data.orderDate,
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                legend: {

                    align: 'top',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },

                series:**series**


            });

          }
       });
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is not an answer Please as questions in the comment seciton

Comment: yes i checked the php.data file and is showing data properly...i by setting the action in form to `<form method="get" action="" >` and it does give correct arrays.

Comment: check my answer again.

Comment: @Pankaj Monga: thank you, but i'm trying something else. i'm using query to fetch data from mysql and save it a json and then use this set of data from json. it gives perfect graphs but when i try to use variable from dropdown menu it is not working for me.