# getajaxdata for multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, json, highcharts

based on the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338254/highchart-mysql-jason-with-dropdown-select-value-for-where-condition/26354890#26354890). which is about using the getajaxdata from a select list to get a variable. i want to use another select list so i'll have 2 different select list with 2 different values. id=list1 and id=list2. what is the correct syntax for this code

```
//on changing select option
$('#list').change(function(){
var val = $('#list').val();
getAjaxData(val);
});
```

to make it getting the two value from the two dropdown lists (list1 and list2). thank you

Comment: So you need to have to change actions on two selects. Then call ajaxs on the last one and initialise chart.

Comment: How?? jscripts are like chinees for me..sorry!!

Comment: Well, it is almost the same scenario as with single select.

Comment: $('#list1').change(function(){
   var val = $('#list1').val();
   getAjaxData(val);
  });
  
  $('#list2').change(function(){
   var val = $('#list2').val();
   getAjaxData(val);
  });
  function getAjaxData(list2){
  
  //use getJSON to get the dynamic data via AJAX call
  $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {.......like that ??